# Use of uninitialized value warning in Perl

Tags: perl

I got following lines of code,

```
foreach ($abc) {
    my ($match) = $_ =~ /([0-9]{5}(?!.*([0-9]{5})))/;
    $zipCode_count{$match} += 1 if $match ne '';
}
```

when I execute it, it keeps throwing such warning:

> Use of uninitialized value $match in string ne at parseZipCode.pl line
>   8,  line 51.

How can I get rid of it? thanks

Comment: please use '\d' for '[0-9]' makes for a good regex.  It likely means your $abc is not an array or your reference is empty etc etc

Comment: Just really helps make things more readable '/(\d{5}(?!.*(\d{5})))/'

Comment: @alexmac: no, in these unicode days, \d means something different than `[0-9]`; if you mean 0-9, that's what you should say (though the newish /a flag lets you still use \d if you prefer)

Comment: 20 years of perl you can also look up the regular expressions in perl \d is all digits and it is POSFIX compliant. [perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) as per Perl.org, stop the madness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$match` will be `undef` if the regex match fails. There is no possible way for `$match` to be the empty string.

Suggested fix: skip the loop if the match failes:

```
my ($match) = /(...)/ or next;
$zipCode_count{$match}++;
```

Alternatively, change the condition to

```
$zipCode_count{$match}++ if defined $match;
```

Further notes:

- increment `++` is usually preferable over `+= 1`.
- A regex matches agains `$_` by default
- `zipCode_count` is a really horrible variable name – either use `camelCase` *or* `snake_case`, but please not both at the same time!